# Django check CSRF token manually

Tags: django, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I am implementing an API that works either with an API key, or with a CSRF token. The goal is for it to be usable either by a web app (protected by CSRF) or by a third party application (protected by API key).

Basically on each request (all via POST), I check if there is an API key. If there is a valid one, it's good to go. If not, I want to fall back to verifying CSRF.

Is there a function I can call to verify the CSRF myself? The view itself is `@csrf_exempt` because API keys need to work.

Comment: You don't need to check on each request, as CSRF tokens should only really be used on POST and PUT requests. Second, you can't verify a CSRF token unless you are generating it on each request, and your verification is _optional_. A CSRF token is not the same as an API key. Please clarify why you need CSRF.

Answer (score 11):

You could probably subclass the CsrfViewMiddleware class and override the process_view method. Then include your custom middleware instead of the default CSRF one.

```
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

class CustomCsrfMiddleware(CsrfViewMiddleware):

    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
        if request.META.get('api_key'):
            # process api key
        else:
            return super(CsrfViewMiddleware, self).process_view(...)
```

Comment: To clarify for others, in order to use your custom middleware, go into your settings.py file for your project, delete the line in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` and add in your own (i.e. `myApp.views.CustomCsrfMiddleware`). Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use builtin csrf verification like this:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

def check_csrf(request):
  reason = CsrfViewMiddleware().process_view(request, None, (), {})
  if reason:
    # CSRF failed
    raise PermissionException() # do what you need to do here
```

Comment: "reason" is always "None" in my case. Is this still working in 2022? (I use class based views)

Answer (score 5):

I've been accessing the `CsrfViewMiddleware` like [Aldarund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29455772/1906307) has shown but more needs to be said about this kind of solution:

1. If you are performing the test in a view, then you can return `reason` directly. According to [how Django middleware works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process-view), when `process_view` returns something else than `None`, then it must be a `HttpResponse` object so it can just be returned by the view.

   There may be cases where you do not want to return `reason` directly, but if there is no reason not to do so, I'd rather return it, for consistency with how the site behaves in other cases.
2. If you use the test in a run-of-the-mill view, and you already use `CsrfViewMiddleware` site-wide, it is usually the case that `request` will already have passed once through `CsrfViewMiddleware`. (Yes, it can happen. I have a case where a request I receive is modified and retested through `CsrfViewMiddleWare` *after* it has already been tested by `CsrfViewMiddleware` due to the site-wide configuration.) However, the middleware sets `csrf_processing_done` on `request` after it tests it and won't retest it if it is called again, because of this flag. So `csrf_processing_done` has to be reset to `False` to perform a second test.

Here's an illustration of the above:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware

def view(request):
    request.csrf_processing_done = False
    reason = CsrfViewMiddleware().process_view(request, None, (), {})
    if reason is not None:
        return reason # Failed the test, stop here.

    # process the request...
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted to POST some raw data with CSRF check.

So, I use this decorator [requires_csrf_token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.requires_csrf_token) in the view which process POST data :

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import requires_csrf_token

@requires_csrf_token
def manage_trade_allocation_update(request):
```

In my template, I added csrf_token génération and put it in data post :

```
{% csrf_token %}
...
data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value;
```

With this mecanism, I can use CSRF protection with manual HTTP POST request.